# How to get dp and dq of CRT-RSA?

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic, side-channel-attack, pkcs1

I am learning to utilize flush+reload method to get private key of CRT-RSA.

CRT-RSA calculates two parts separately:  `mp = c^dp mod p` and `mq = c^dq mod q`

`x = b^e mod m` is calculated by the code below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

There is a loophole in this method, that is, the execution of Square-Reduce-Multiply-Reduce in the code can be detected, and the exponent can be inferred.

> Square-Reduce-Multiply-Reduce indicate a set bit. Sequences of
> Square-Reduce which are not followed by Multiply indicate a clear bit.

According to the introduction of the paper, as long as the Square-Reduce-Multiply in the encryption process is detected, the private key can also be restored.

> Hence, knowing dp (and, symmetrically, dq) is sufficient for factoring
> n and breaking the encryption

By reading the paper and source code, I found that he always checks whether the following three cache lines are used when decrypting.

For gnupg, flush+reload detects the execution of the following three lines of code.

```
    probe 0x080f7607 S #mpih-mul.c:270 (First cache line in mpih_sqr_n())
    probe 0x080f6c45 r #mpih-div.c:329 (Loop in default case in mpihelp_divrem())
    probe 0x080f6fa8 M #mpih-mul.c:121 (First cache line of mul_n())
```

1. I'm confused, does the execution of the above three lines of code restore dp or dq?
2. For Gnupg, I am able to export the private key by command `gpg --output mike.secret.gpg --armor --export-secret-key mike@site.com`, but how do I figure out what dp and dq are?

I've been trying for weeks and I still can't figure it out.
Can anyone help? thank you very much!!!

Comment: The hint seems to be in the "detection" part. Detecting if specific code is executed according to input values can lead to side channel attacks.

Comment: Do you know how to get dp and dq based on the RSA private key? Thanks!

Comment: $d_p = d \bmod (p-1)$ and $d_q = d \bmod (q-1)$